# Java Spring MVC - Send JSON request body error

Tags: java, json, spring

I am trying to send a JSON string as a request to my application. This is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/mylink/upload",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes ="application/json",
        produces = "application/json")
public
@ResponseBody
List<Upload> upload(
        @RequestParam(value = "hdfsLocation") String hdfsLocation

) throws Exception {
    return S3HdfsTransfer.uploadFromHDFS(hdfsLocation);
}
```

I am trying to send a request with Postman. The method I use is POST, the header contains: Accept "application/json",Content-Type "application/json", the request body is the following:

```
{
    "hdfsLocation" : "hdfs://145.160.10.10:8020"
}
```

This is the response I get. If I put the parameter in the URL, it works.

```
{
  "httpStatus": 500,
  "appErrorId": 0,
  "message": "Required String parameter 'hdfsLocation' is not present",
  "trackingId": "8c6d45fd-2da5-47ea-a213-3d4ea5764681"
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Serban

Comment: try to change your return type

Comment: can you remove the content-type and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have confused `@RequestBody` with `@RequestParam`. Do either of following :

- Pass the request param as a request param(not as a body). Like, (encoded)

  http://example.com?hdfsLocation=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3FhdfsLocation%3Dhdfs%3A%2F%2F145.160.10.10%3A8020
- Replace the `@RequestParam` with `@RequestBody`. If you are sending a body, don't send it along with request param. Those are two different things.

I guess you over looked :)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestParam`? 
Also, even after using `@RequestBody`, the whole of the JSON string:

`{
    "hdfsLocation" : "hdfs://145.160.10.10:8020"
}`

will be the value of `String hdfsLocation` and not just the hdfs url. Hence, you'll have to JSON parse that JSON by yourself to get just the hdfs url.